# TableAdapter: Number of query values and destination fields are not the same

Tags: vb.net, dataset, tableadapter

I have been scratching my head about why this `TableAdapter` is giving me the error `Number of query values and destination fields are not the same` when calling the Update command for a couple days now. It looks good to me, with 5 parameters everywhere except where previously spotted in the comments, but obviously there is something I am missing.

[image: TableAdapter]

[image: Query Builder]

[image: Parameters]

[image: Table in Database]

Here's the relevant portions of the xml backing it:

```
    <TableAdapter BaseClass="System.ComponentModel.Component" DataAccessorModifier="AutoLayout, AnsiClass, Class, Public" DataAccessorName="UomListTableAdapter" GeneratorDataComponentClassName="UomListTableAdapter" Name="UomList" UserDataComponentName="UomListTableAdapter">
            <MainSource>
              <DbSource ConnectionRef="DataConnectionString (MySettings)" DbObjectName="UomList" DbObjectType="Table" FillMethodModifier="Public" FillMethodName="Fill" GenerateMethods="Both" GenerateShortCommands="true" GeneratorGetMethodName="GetData" GeneratorSourceName="Fill" GetMethodModifier="Public" GetMethodName="GetData" QueryType="Rowset" ScalarCallRetval="System.Object, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" UseOptimisticConcurrency="true" UserGetMethodName="GetData" UserSourceName="Fill">
                <DeleteCommand>
                  <DbCommand CommandType="Text" ModifiedByUser="true">
                    <CommandText>DELETE FROM UomList
WHERE        (SetID = ?) AND (Name = ?)</CommandText>
                    <Parameters>
                      <Parameter AllowDbNull="true" AutogeneratedName="Param1" ColumnName="" DataSourceName="" DataTypeServer="unknown" DbType="String" Direction="Input" ParameterName="SetID" Precision="0" ProviderType="VarWChar" Scale="0" Size="50" SourceColumn="SetID" SourceColumnNullMapping="false" SourceVersion="Original" />
                      <Parameter AllowDbNull="false" AutogeneratedName="Param2" ColumnName="" DataSourceName="" DataTypeServer="unknown" DbType="String" Direction="Input" ParameterName="Name" Precision="0" ProviderType="VarWChar" Scale="0" Size="31" SourceColumn="Name" SourceColumnNullMapping="false" SourceVersion="Original" />
                    </Parameters>
                  </DbCommand>
                </DeleteCommand>
                <InsertCommand>
                  <DbCommand CommandType="Text" ModifiedByUser="true">
                    <CommandText>INSERT INTO UomList
                         (SetID, Name, Abbr, Qty, IsBase)
VALUES        (?, ?, ?, ?)</CommandText>
                    <Parameters>
                      <Parameter AllowDbNull="true" AutogeneratedName="Param3" ColumnName="SetID" DataSourceName="" DataTypeServer="unknown" DbType="String" Direction="Input" ParameterName="SetID" Precision="0" ProviderType="VarWChar" Scale="0" Size="50" SourceColumn="SetID" SourceColumnNullMapping="false" SourceVersion="Current" />
                      <Parameter AllowDbNull="false" AutogeneratedName="Param4" ColumnName="Name" DataSourceName="" DataTypeServer="unknown" DbType="String" Direction="Input" ParameterName="Name" Precision="0" ProviderType="VarWChar" Scale="0" Size="31" SourceColumn="Name" SourceColumnNullMapping="false" SourceVersion="Current" />
                      <Parameter AllowDbNull="false" AutogeneratedName="Param5" ColumnName="Abbr" DataSourceName="" DataTypeServer="unknown" DbType="String" Direction="Input" ParameterName="Abbr" Precision="0" ProviderType="VarWChar" Scale="0" Size="31" SourceColumn="Abbr" SourceColumnNullMapping="false" SourceVersion="Current" />
                      <Parameter AllowDbNull="false" AutogeneratedName="Param6" ColumnName="Qty" DataSourceName="" DataTypeServer="unknown" DbType="Double" Direction="Input" ParameterName="Qty" Precision="0" ProviderType="Double" Scale="0" Size="0" SourceColumn="Qty" SourceColumnNullMapping="false" SourceVersion="Current" />
                      <Parameter AllowDbNull="false" AutogeneratedName="Param1" ColumnName="IsBase" DataSourceName="" DataTypeServer="unknown" DbType="Boolean" Direction="Input" ParameterName="IsBase" Precision="0" ProviderType="Boolean" Scale="0" Size="0" SourceColumn="IsBase" SourceColumnNullMapping="false" SourceVersion="Current" />
                    </Parameters>
                  </DbCommand>
                </InsertCommand>
                <SelectCommand>
                  <DbCommand CommandType="Text" ModifiedByUser="true">
                    <CommandText>SELECT        SetID, Name, Abbr, Qty, IsBase
FROM            UomList</CommandText>
                    <Parameters />
                  </DbCommand>
                </SelectCommand>
                <UpdateCommand>
                  <DbCommand CommandType="Text" ModifiedByUser="true">
                    <CommandText>UPDATE       UomList
SET                Abbr = ?, Qty = ?, IsBase = ?
WHERE        (SetID = ?) AND (Name = ?)</CommandText>
                    <Parameters>
                      <Parameter AllowDbNull="false" AutogeneratedName="Param1" ColumnName="Abbr" DataSourceName="" DataTypeServer="unknown" DbType="String" Direction="Input" ParameterName="Abbr" Precision="0" ProviderType="VarWChar" Scale="0" Size="31" SourceColumn="Abbr" SourceColumnNullMapping="false" SourceVersion="Current" />
                      <Parameter AllowDbNull="false" AutogeneratedName="Param2" ColumnName="Qty" DataSourceName="" DataTypeServer="unknown" DbType="Double" Direction="Input" ParameterName="Qty" Precision="0" ProviderType="Double" Scale="0" Size="0" SourceColumn="Qty" SourceColumnNullMapping="false" SourceVersion="Current" />
                      <Parameter AllowDbNull="false" AutogeneratedName="Param3" ColumnName="IsBase" DataSourceName="" DataTypeServer="unknown" DbType="Boolean" Direction="Input" ParameterName="IsBase" Precision="0" ProviderType="Boolean" Scale="0" Size="0" SourceColumn="IsBase" SourceColumnNullMapping="false" SourceVersion="Current" />
                      <Parameter AllowDbNull="true" AutogeneratedName="Param4" ColumnName="SetID" DataSourceName="" DataTypeServer="unknown" DbType="String" Direction="Input" ParameterName="Original_SetID" Precision="0" ProviderType="VarWChar" Scale="0" Size="50" SourceColumn="SetID" SourceColumnNullMapping="false" SourceVersion="Original" />
                      <Parameter AllowDbNull="false" AutogeneratedName="Param5" ColumnName="Name" DataSourceName="" DataTypeServer="unknown" DbType="String" Direction="Input" ParameterName="Original_Name" Precision="0" ProviderType="VarWChar" Scale="0" Size="31" SourceColumn="Name" SourceColumnNullMapping="false" SourceVersion="Original" />
                    </Parameters>
                  </DbCommand>
                </UpdateCommand>
              </DbSource>
            </MainSource>
            <Mappings>
              <Mapping SourceColumn="SetID" DataSetColumn="SetID" />
              <Mapping SourceColumn="Name" DataSetColumn="Name" />
              <Mapping SourceColumn="Abbr" DataSetColumn="Abbr" />
              <Mapping SourceColumn="Qty" DataSetColumn="Qty" />
              <Mapping SourceColumn="IsBase" DataSetColumn="IsBase" />
            </Mappings>
            <Sources />
          </TableAdapter>



        <xs:element name="UomList" msprop:Generator_UserTableName="UomList" msprop:Generator_RowDeletedName="UomListRowDeleted" msprop:Generator_RowChangedName="UomListRowChanged" msprop:Generator_RowClassName="UomListRow" msprop:Generator_RowChangingName="UomListRowChanging" msprop:Generator_RowEvArgName="UomListRowChangeEvent" msprop:Generator_RowEvHandlerName="UomListRowChangeEventHandler" msprop:Generator_TableClassName="UomListDataTable" msprop:Generator_TableVarName="tableUomList" msprop:Generator_RowDeletingName="UomListRowDeleting" msprop:Generator_TablePropName="UomList">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="SetID" msprop:Generator_UserColumnName="SetID" msprop:Generator_ColumnPropNameInRow="SetID" msprop:Generator_ColumnVarNameInTable="columnSetID" msprop:Generator_ColumnPropNameInTable="SetIDColumn" minOccurs="0">
                <xs:simpleType>
                  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                    <xs:maxLength value="50" />
                  </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="Name" msprop:Generator_UserColumnName="Name" msprop:Generator_ColumnPropNameInRow="Name" msprop:Generator_ColumnVarNameInTable="columnName" msprop:Generator_ColumnPropNameInTable="NameColumn">
                <xs:simpleType>
                  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                    <xs:maxLength value="31" />
                  </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="Abbr" msprop:Generator_UserColumnName="Abbr" msprop:Generator_ColumnPropNameInRow="Abbr" msprop:Generator_ColumnVarNameInTable="columnAbbr" msprop:Generator_ColumnPropNameInTable="AbbrColumn" minOccurs="0">
                <xs:simpleType>
                  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                    <xs:maxLength value="31" />
                  </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="Qty" msprop:Generator_UserColumnName="Qty" msprop:Generator_ColumnPropNameInRow="Qty" msprop:Generator_ColumnVarNameInTable="columnQty" msprop:Generator_ColumnPropNameInTable="QtyColumn" type="xs:double" minOccurs="0" />
              <xs:element name="IsBase" msprop:Generator_UserColumnName="IsBase" msprop:Generator_ColumnPropNameInRow="IsBase" msprop:Generator_ColumnVarNameInTable="columnIsBase" msprop:Generator_ColumnPropNameInTable="IsBaseColumn" type="xs:boolean" minOccurs="0" />
              <xs:element name="ListDisplay" msdata:ReadOnly="true" msdata:Expression="IIF(SetID = '', Name, Name + '     ' + Qty)" msprop:Generator_UserColumnName="ListDisplay" msprop:Generator_ColumnPropNameInRow="ListDisplay" msprop:Generator_ColumnVarNameInTable="columnListDisplay" msprop:Generator_ColumnPropNameInTable="ListDisplayColumn" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
              <xs:element name="SelDisplay" msdata:ReadOnly="true" msdata:Expression="IIF(SetID = '', Qty, Abbr + '(' + Qty + ')')" msprop:Generator_UserColumnName="SelDisplay" msprop:Generator_ColumnPropNameInRow="SelDisplay" msprop:Generator_ColumnVarNameInTable="columnSelDisplay" msprop:Generator_ColumnPropNameInTable="SelDisplayColumn" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>



    <xs:unique name="UomKey1" msdata:PrimaryKey="true">
      <xs:selector xpath=".//mstns:UomList" />
      <xs:field xpath="mstns:SetID" />
      <xs:field xpath="mstns:Name" />
    </xs:unique>
```

Where is the mismatch in number of parameters?

Comment: Looking at the XML it seems the Insert command seems to have 4 question marks and 5 parameters. The 4 is probably correct assuming the SetID field is auto-increment. I assume this is all generated code and your are calling an Update on the table adapter.

Comment: Oops, I forgot to specify that this is happening on the Update command. And no, the SetID is not auto-incremented; 5 is correct. Fixing my question now.

Comment: When you call the Update on the TableAdapter, it will call the Insert, Update and Delete commands as necessary depending on the state of the rows in the DataTable. Perhaps the error in the Insert was triggered as the TableAdapter was checking the commands.

Comment: Yeah, I was just coming back to comment that that was it. I spent all my time looking in Update, it never occurred to me to check Insert. Thank you! If you want to write it up, I'll accept it as the Answer,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reviewing the XML it seems the Insert command seems to have 4 question marks and 5 parameters.

```
<InsertCommand>
                  <DbCommand CommandType="Text" ModifiedByUser="true">
                    <CommandText>INSERT INTO UomList (SetID, Name, Abbr, Qty, IsBase) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)
                    </CommandText>
```

The Error referencing "Update" is probably about TableAdapter.Update not necessarily the Update command. The TableAdapter.Update is calling the Insert, Update, and Delete commands as needed depending on the state of the rows in the DataTable.